# R: Restructuring Data for Survival Analysis

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data on medical patients:

```
my_data = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), status_2017 = c("alive", "alive", "alive"), status_2018 = c("alive", "dead", "alive"), status_2019 = c("alive", "dead", "dead"), height_2017 = rnorm(3,3,3), height_2018 = rnorm(3,3,3), 
                     height_2019 = rnorm(3,3,3) , weight_2017  = rnorm(3,3,3), weight_2018 = rnorm(3,3,3), weight_2019 = rnorm(3,3,3))

cols <- colnames(my_data)
ix <- my_data[, startsWith(cols, "status")] == "dead"

my_data[, startsWith(cols, "height")][ ix ] <- NA
my_data[, startsWith(cols, "weight")][ ix ] <- NA
```

This looks something like this:

```
 id status_2017 status_2018 status_2019 height_2017 height_2018 height_2019 weight_2017 weight_2018 weight_2019
1  1       alive       alive       alive   3.7276706    4.524869   -1.648458   -1.702781    7.755581    3.369895
2  2       alive        dead        dead   0.7539518          NA          NA    1.060408          NA          NA
3  3       alive       alive        dead   6.6213771    2.122374          NA    5.114120    1.851467          NA
```

**My Question:** I want to restructure this data such that:

- Each patient has its own row for each year
- There is a "year" column
- Status_2017, Status_2018, Status_2019 are all combined into a single column (i.e. "status")
- Height_2017, Height_2018, Height_2019 are all combined into a single column (i.e. "height")
- Weight_2017, Weight_2018, Weight_2019 are all combined into a single column (i.e. "weight")
- A new variable ("new_var") is created such that if a patient id has a row with 2019 then new_var is always 0 - for all other patient id's, new_var is 0 until the max year (and new_var then is 1)

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_data_long <- na.omit(my_data %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -c(id, status_2017),
                 names_to = c(".value", "year"),
                 names_pattern = "(height|weight)_(\\d{4})") %>%
    arrange(id, year))


final = my_data_long  %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    new_var = ifelse(any(year == "2019"), 0, 1),
    max_year = max(year)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    new_var = ifelse(year == max_year & new_var == 1, 1, 0),
    max_year = NULL
  )
```

The final result looks something like this:

```
> final
# A tibble: 6 x 6
     id status_2017 year  height weight new_var
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 alive       2017   2.39    2.27       0
2     1 alive       2018  -0.541   1.63       0
3     1 alive       2019  -1.93   10.1        0
4     2 alive       2017   4.18   -3.35       1
5     3 alive       2017  -1.35    7.12       0
6     3 alive       2018   1.42    1.70       1
```

My end goal is to restructure this dataset such that I can fit a "time varying survival analysis model" (e.g. cox-ph) to this data (e.g. https://atm.amegroups.com/article/view/18820/html, https://cran.r-project.org/web/pacacages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf)

**Can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly?**

Thanks!

- Note: I tried to add time differences for each ID

This looks something like this:

```
library(stringr)

final %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(start = 0:(n() - 1),
         end = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 8
     id status_2017 year  height weight new_var start   end
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1 alive       2017   2.39    2.27       0     0     1
2     1 alive       2018  -0.541   1.63       0     1     2
3     1 alive       2019  -1.93   10.1        0     2     3
4     2 alive       2017   4.18   -3.35       1     0     1
5     3 alive       2017  -1.35    7.12       0     0     1
6     3 alive       2018   1.42    1.70       1     1     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we need the `status` column, then we have to include those also in the pivoting to long i.e. `cols = -c(id, status_2017)` removes the 'status_2017' from reshaping.  In addition, the `names_pattern` needs to include the `status` as well in addition to `height` and `weight`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
library(tidyr)
my_data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = c(".value", "year"),
   names_pattern = "(height|weight|status)_(\\d{4})") %>%
  drop_na() %>% 
 mutate(new_var = +(2019 %in% year), max_year = max(year), .by = "id") %>% 
 mutate(new_var = +(year == max_year & new_var), max_year = NULL)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 6
     id year  status height weight new_var
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <int>
1     1 2017  alive   9.54   7.47        0
2     1 2018  alive   6.49   5.23        0
3     1 2019  alive   3.75   1.93        1
4     2 2017  alive   4.21   0.619       0
5     3 2017  alive   1.97   5.32        0
6     3 2018  alive  -0.406  8.00        0
```